# Postman request : ImportError: cannot import name DEFAULT_CIPHERS

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, postman, boto3

I'm using a Red Hat EC2 instance in order to run AWS CLI commands and manage some tasks with Glacier and S3. I'm also designing a Rest API in order to execute the scripts I've deployed on the EC2. Using Postman to send a POST request to the EC2's public DNS address, my script will take in a raw JSON and decode it for parameters my PHP script will take in. I run into an error when I try to execute the AWS CLI commands within my PHP script. The AWS commands work when I run them in the terminal.

Things I have tried from this thread

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3542:

- pip install AWScli instead of pip install AWS
- downgrading AWSversions and Botocore

Postman Response

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 30, in <module>
    import botocore.credentials
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 42, in <module>
    from botocore.utils import InstanceMetadataFetcher, parse_key_val_file
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    import botocore.httpsession
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 7, in <module>
    from urllib3.util.ssl_ import (
ImportError: cannot import name DEFAULT_CIPHERS
```

Php Script

```
exec("aws s3 cp s3://$BucketName /path/to/dir/ --recursive 2>&1",$output,$return);
```

I expected the AWS CLI commands to be executed by the exec command and return a string output, which I would send back as a response.

Answer (score 9):

Fixed this problem by running this command

```
sudo pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, this fixed the problem:

```
sudo pip install boto3 --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

just in case, try this step later:

```
sudo pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

Comment: You save my life, while I deploy to prod env, boom... incident, my heart goes out...

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message as well, but it was caused by a damaged install of
`python-urllib3`

```
yum reinstall python-urllib3
```

sorted it for me.  Initial cause was because we'd used `pip` to install urllib3 and yum got confused.